# Angular Dir-Pagination and calling controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I have an angular html snippet below of a table I am trying to wire up using [Dir-Paginate](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination) and also have the table row change class based on a function on the controller.js

```
<tr dir-pagination="response in vm.responses  | toArray | orderBy:'-completionTime' | itemsPerPage: $root.pagination.itemsPerPage" class="{{ vm.getRowClass($index) }}">
    <td> {{ $index + 1 }}</td>
    <td><a ui-sref="response({uri:response.uri})">{{ response.name }}</a></td>
    <td><a href="mailto:{{ response.email }}">{{ response.email }}</a></td>
 <tr>

<dir-pagination-controls ng-show="appvm.showDataTable()" boundary-links="true" on-page-change="pageChangeHandler(newPageNumber)" template-url="ng/pagination"></dir-pagination-controls>
```

If i remove all of the Dir-Pagination syntax and make it just a normal `ng-repeat` the `vm.getRowClass($index)` works as it should, changing the class based on the function's logic. However, when I try to add the dir-pagination syntax in, i am given a `$Index is undefined` error.

Problem seems to be that Dir-Paginate does not allow me to pass in an `$index` or any item on the same line as the `<tr>`

Comment: Do you mean `dir-paginate` instead of `dir-pagination`?  Also try `ng-class` instead of just `class`.  I am passing `$index` into an `ng-click` function and it's taking just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comment and some playing around i found the solution.

I needed to add `track by $index` to the end of the `itemsPerPage: $root.pagination.itemsPerPage` area.

Shown correctly below.

```
<tr dir-pagination="response in vm.responses  | toArray | orderBy:'-completionTime' | itemsPerPage: $root.pagination.itemsPerPage track by $index" class="{{ vm.getRowClass($index) }}">
    <td> {{ $index + 1 }}</td>
    <td><a ui-sref="response({uri:response.uri})">{{ response.name }}</a></td>
    <td><a href="mailto:{{ response.email }}">{{ response.email }}</a></td>
 <tr>
```